# 'Unmatched open brace' error when adding item to ttk.Treeview

Tags: python, treeview, tkinter

I'm attempting to add an item to a `ttk.Treeview` instance in my Python script that builds a basic UI. The insertion code looks like this:

```
tree.insert(my_id, 
            'end', 
            todo_id, 
            text="Line " + str(line_num), 
            values=(str(todo_text), owner), # I have 2 cols, 'text' and 'owner'
            tags=['#todo_entry'])
```

I'm finding that when setting the string `todo_text` in the column named 'text', Tkinter throws an error when it encounters a particular string:

**_tkinter.TclError: unmatched open brace in list**

and the only thing I can think of as the reason for this, is that the string in question contains a curly brace. Here is the string it broke on:

`'//    static class Properties { // TODO, temp class'`

This seems to happen whether or not I use `todo_text` or `str(todo_text)`.

Is the text string being *parsed* somehow? What am I missing?

Comment: Since the error refers to a list, perhaps it *is* parsing your text. Have you tried other text strings? I would try to determine the simplest text string that works then, add different characters until it fails.

Comment: I have several other strings that do work. The only difference I've noticed is that this one has a '{' in it...

Comment: This is a complete stab in the dark, but what about `str(todo_text).replace('{',r'\{')` ?

Comment: Thanks @mgilson, that worked but I'd love to understand why?!

Comment: Also, @mgilson, what is that 'r' preceding the second param in `replace()`?

Comment: @scorpiodawg -- It makes it a raw string.  For example `'\n'` is a newline, `r'\n'` is the literal 2 character string backslash n.  In this case, the r doesn't really do anything since `'\{'` isn't an escape sequence, but it's a habit of mine.  Whenever I have a backslash and I don't have any escape sequences, I just use raw strings ... Basically, my thinking was that if `Tk` is a sane language specification, it should allow curly braces to be escaped like other things are escaped in other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @mgilson. [Another way](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65211-convert-a-string-into-a-raw-string/) to do this is to say: `"%r"%todo_text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At it's core, Tkinter is a wrapper around a Tcl interpreter. To Tcl, curly braces are special unless they are escaped. Curly braces are the most common way to create a Tcl list. If you see `unmatched open brace in list`, that's a Tcl error related to the fact that you have unbalanced braces.

This looks like a Tkinter bug to me -- the tkinter wrapper is incorrectly quoting data before passing it on to the Tcl interpreter. When you place a backslash in front of the curly brace, this now becomes a valid Tcl string, which is why you no longer see the error.

This has been reported on the python bug tracker as issue [#15861](http://bugs.python.org/issue15861)

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter sits on top of Tcl, which uses braces as a kind of quote.

It looks like Tkinter is quoting the string with braces for Tcl, but not escaping any which happen to be in the string itself.